# How to convert datagrid data to tree structure ,and whether it can improve search speed?

Tags: c#

I try to resolve a telephone business problem,say there are very huge call records,each of them mainly contain  "caller num","called num","start datetime","duration time".

the original data was stored in excel and i have import them into infragistics's ultragrid control,
say it is grid_A.

what i want to do is :for a certain call record outside grid_A, search grid_A and find if there is a  matching record.there matching mean the two records have same "caller num" ,"called num",and the two records  have similar "start datetime","duration time",for example,their "start datetime" is
00:10:00 and 00:12:00 ,just 2 mins different.

because such compare will also be done many times and  current search code is too slow,I think if i can change the grid data into a tree structure.
the tree i image is this form:
the first level is "caller num",assume 100 nodes of "caller num",
below it ,is "called num",assume for each "caller num", there may have 1-10 "called num"
last level is "start time" and "duration time".

what i want to know is :if this structure can be accomplish with c# and how to do it ,whether this structure can improve my search much.

Look forward to your help.

Comment: Why don't you store the information in a `Database` you can Import the data that's in the excel file into SQL Server for example using `DTS` or SSIS` even better you could probably create your own Export/Import Class to extract the data into your own Object and do your searching from there..why would you want to store the information into a `Tree` not sure.. I think storing into a DataGridView would be perfect..sounds like the problem in not in the DataGrid but in the process of how the data is Stored then searched.. do you have current / existing code to display how you are doing this

Comment: the tree i mentioned is not treeview control,it like binary tree or something else. i don't want to save these data into database because the original excel files come from different company and have different format,what i really need is just the four column i mentioned,but if i try to store them into database,then for each format,i must write a different store_to_database method.

Comment: You can create your own file structure using an `enum` to layout the file structure, this is not very difficult I think that personally you are making this harder than it needs to be.. You could store this data into a Custom List<T> or a List<string> or a Dictionary or Hashtable personally without seeing what you currently have all I can do is offer better solutions based on what it is you are wanting.. and Binary Tree.. still I think there are better ways to approach your problem with a more efficient solution. Database should not hinder you..

Comment: That's the pleasure of being a coder you can code to make this work for what ever needs you find necessary and if you know the file layout of the different companies you could still create this dynamically to make it work..trust me I did this for a large Dept of Defense contract I was working on and never had any issues with reading in `comma` separated files / searches..

Answer (score 0):

> what i want to do is :for a certain call record outside grid_A, search grid_A and find if there is a matching record.there matching mean the two records have same "caller num" ,"called num",and the two records have similar "start datetime","duration time",for example,their "start datetime" is
>   00:10:00 and 00:12:00 ,just 2 mins different.

It sounds like you are trying to do a search on the records displayed in your grid, although I will admit I had a difficult time parsing your language.

If this is the case, and since you only have four columns, I recommend creating an index (`Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>>`) on all of your records that takes `caller num` and `called num` and stores it as the key (the value would be the row objects that match the given key).  Then, you can efficiently find match candidates, and use Linq to sort through the (ideally much smaller) subset of records to find records that further meet your criteria.

In fact, in thinking about it, this approach turns the problem into a map-reduce problem, where the map phase is the querying of the individual index entries to find ones that match.  The linq queries can be executed in parallel to further speed your execution time.

Comment: you said: takes caller num and called num and stores it as the key . if i do not make mistake,you mean combine the caller num and called num ,and generate a hashcode as key.but in the grid,there are many record which have same caller num and called num ,so the hashcode will not unique,does key allow duplicate?

Comment: In this case, yes - you would not need to generate hash code - just combine them as strings, let the dictionary generate the hash code for you.  And for multiple items under the same key, the dictionary value is an IEnumerable, so all those items get collected and placed under one dictionary key.